# Iterating through parallel array's to determine the largest number in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to Stack Overflow and C++, so please excuse if I am asking this question in the incorrect format. I am struggling to answer the below question, I have posted my code below as well, please may I ask for some guidance?

*Use two parallel arrays to keep track of the number of subscriptions for each of their
50 publications. Array "publications" holds the names of the magazines and newspapers published
and array "subscriptions" holds the number of subscriptions for each corresponding magazine or
newspaper. You have to write a void function, called findMostSubs to determine which publication
has the most subscribers. Function findMostSubs has to return the name of the publication as well as the number of subscribers to that publication.
Assume the following global constant: NUM_PUBS = 50;*

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int NUM_PUBS = 5;

void findMostSubs(string pubsP[NUM_PUBS], int subsP[NUM_PUBS], string mostSubsP, int nrMostSubsP)
{
   for (int i; i < NUM_PUBS; i++)
   {
      cout << "Please enter the name of the publication: ";
      cin >> pubsP[i];
      cout << "Please enter the number of subscriptions: ";
      cin >> subsP[i];
   }
   
   for (int i; i < NUM_PUBS; i++)
   {
      nrMostSubsP = 0;
      if (subsP[i] > nrMostSubsP)
      {
         nrMostSubsP = subsP[i];
         cout << nrMostSubsP;
      }
   }
}

int main()
{

   string publications[NUM_PUBS];
   int subscriptions[NUM_PUBS];
   int nrMostSubscriptions;
   string mostSubscriptions;

   findMostSubs(publications, subscriptions, mostSubscriptions, nrMostSubscriptions);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i; i < NUM_PUBS; i++){ nrMostSubsP = 0;` -- What does the logic here indicate to you?  Should you be resetting the maximum value back to 0 each time the loop iterates?

Comment: Also you should initialize `i` in all your loops.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you, I definitely don't want to set the max to 0 each time. I am going to try an initialize max to 0 at the beginning before the for loop.

Comment: Thank you cigien. I will do that and try complete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two last parameters of findMostSub should be declared as reference to use them as output:

```
void findMostSubs(string pubsP[NUM_PUBS], int subsP[NUM_PUBS], string& mostSubsP, int& nrMostSubsP)
{
   for (int i; i < NUM_PUBS; i++)
   {
      cout << "Please enter the name of the publication: ";
      cin >> pubsP[i];
      cout << "Please enter the number of subscriptions: ";
      cin >> subsP[i];
   }

   nrMostSubsP = subsP[0];   
   mostSubsP = pubsP[0];

   for (int i = 1; i < NUM_PUBS; i++)
   {
      if (subsP[i] > nrMostSubsP)
      {
         nrMostSubsP = subsP[i];
         mostSubsP = pubsP[i];
      }
   }
}

int main()
{

   string publications[NUM_PUBS];
   int subscriptions[NUM_PUBS];
   int nrMostSubscriptions;
   string mostSubscriptions;

   findMostSubs(publications, subscriptions, mostSubscriptions, nrMostSubscriptions);

   cout << "Most Subscriptions : " << mostSubscriptions << " , " << nrMostSubscriptions << endl;
   return 0;
}
```